# Why is Math undefined in new Function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm running a discord bot, and one of the features I have added is simple maths calculations. The code (rough) for such is as follows:

```js
class Bot{
  constructor(){
    this.prefix = '!';
    this.client = new Client();
    this.clinet.on('message', message => this.onMessage(message))

  }
  onMessage(message){
    const content = message.content;
    try{
      const result = new Function(`return ${content.slice(this.prefix.length + 'solve '.length)}`)();
      message.channel.send(result)
    }catch(err){
      message.channel.send("Error" + err)
    }

  }
}
```

This is of course wrapped in `try - catch`, and simple maths equations (`5 + 5`, `10*170`, `2*(6-13)/17` etc) work fine. The issue is when I need more complex things, such as `cos` or `sqrt`. Normally I would get these from the `Math` object, so `Math.cos()` or `Math.sqrt`. However when I input this into the command it simply returns `Math is not defined`. I know that scope might have something to do with this, but is there any way to fix it?

Edit: Here are some of the messages that would cause errors:

```
!solve Math.cos(5)
!solve Math.sqrt(4)
!solve Math.sin(50) * Math.PI
!solve 5 * Math.floor(5.1)
etc.
```

Comment: What does the input look like? What are `content`, `this` and `this.prefix`? What scope is `const result` in?

Comment: Where is this code running? Math should be a global variable in most contexts, but you could be running this code in an environment that doesn't have access to `Math`, or in a place where `Math` is in a different place than you expect. I'm not familiar with Discord bots enough to know where the code is executed.

Comment: Note that it can be very dangerous to let users execute arbitrary code. The environment might have security measures in place that limit what's available.

Comment: @GuyIncognito yes, that is also an issue that I am looking to address, however considering who I am using this bot with, I doubt this will be an issue (at least right now)

Comment: Please post examples of message `content`s you are receiving that lead to the error. We can't help you without an [mcve]